# msmtp: GSSAPI authentication fails

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ntlm, gssapi, msmtp

I'm trying to send emails using MSMTP with NTLM or GSSAPI authentication. This works fine using the NTLM authentication, but fails while using the GSSAPI.

```
msmtp --version
```

**Output**

```
msmtp version 1.6.6
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
TLS/SSL library: GnuTLS
Authentication library: GNU SASL
Supported authentication methods:
plain scram-sha-1 external gssapi cram-md5 digest-md5 login ntlm
IDN support: enabled
NLS: enabled, LOCALEDIR is /usr/share/locale
Keyring support: none
System configuration file name: /etc/msmtprc
User configuration file name: /home/XXXX/.msmtprc
```

**Command used for sending email**

```
printf "Subject: Using GSSAPI\n\nTest message 1 using GSSAPI." | msmtp userid@somedomain.name
```

**Error message**

```
msmtp: GNU SASL: GSSAPI error in client while negotiating security context in gss_init_sec_context() in SASL library.  This is most likely due insufficient credentials or malicious interactions.
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
```

**System configuration file**

```
auth gssapi
timeout 10
tls on
#tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
tls_certcheck off
logfile /var/log/xxxx/msmtp.log
host <<hostname>>
port 587
from username@somedomain.name
user username@somedomain.name
password <<password>>
```

Wanting to know if I'm missing any configuration steps/commands or implementing something wrong. Any kind help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SASL will delegate to MIT Kerberos/Heimdal. You need to do a `kinit` first. Do export `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr` and you'll see what MIT Kerberos does.

Comment: Do I need to have Heimdal on my system? Apologies for asking this naive question, I'm a newbie here with MSMTP GSSAPI authentication.

Comment: @VikramV No, MIT Kerberos. As far as I know, `KRB5_TRACE` works for MIT Kerberos only. Check with your OS what is used by GNU SASL.